# Как идеально ровно нарисовать меню бургер в процентах

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

изучаю css  с нуля и хочу вывести формулу чтобы всегда бургер преобразовывался в крестик, пытаюсь играть translateY, но получается если чуть изменить он уже не преобразуется в крестик при нажатие, как можно задать данные параметр чтобы всегда образовывался идеально ровный крестик? сейчас он немножко кривой [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  .hamb__field.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(12px) rotate(45deg);

  }
  .hamb__field.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-12px) rotate(-45deg);

  }
```

```js
const hamb = document.querySelector("#hamb");
const popup = document.querySelector("#popup");
const menu = document.querySelector("#menu").cloneNode(1);
const body = document.body;

hamb.addEventListener("click", hambHandler);

function hambHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  popup.classList.toggle("open");
  hamb.classList.toggle("active");
  body.classList.toggle("noscroll");
  renderPopup();
}

function renderPopup() {
  popup.appendChild(menu);
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}


.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background: #7a52b3;
}



/* меню бургер */
.hamb {
  display: none;
}

/* расположение обьектов в меню бургер */
.popup {
  display: none;
}




 .menu {
  display: flex;
}



.navbar__wrap .menu > li > a {
 
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}





@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar__wrap .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .hamb {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .hamb__field {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
  
  }
  .bar {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 4px;
    margin: 6px auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: 0.2s;
  }
  .popup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 75px;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  .popup.open {
    left: 0;
  }
  /* контент в меню бургере */
  .popup .menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: start;
    padding: 50px 0;
    overflow: auto;
    
  }

  /* контент в меню бургере */
  .popup .menu > li > a {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #3f3f3f;
  }

  .hamb__field.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .hamb__field.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(12px) rotate(45deg);

  }
  .hamb__field.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-12px) rotate(-45deg);

  }
  body.noscroll {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Adaptive header for site</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar__wrap">
          <div class="hamb">
            <div class="hamb__field" id="hamb">
              <span class="bar"></span>
              <span class="bar"></span>
              <span class="bar"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
 
          <ul class="menu" id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Benefits</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="popup" id="popup"></div>

 

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `transform` всегда странно работает, Вам нужно будет слишком усложнить себе жизнь, чтобы идеально высчитывать всё. Проблема же в том, что изменения происходят от позиции блока, позиции разные, собственно, и всё всегда по-разному...

Comment: То есть только примерно подогнать?

Comment: или другими средствами рисовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В процентах тоже можно. Для этого нужно бары обернуть в еще один div и добавить `overflow: hidden` в обёртку, чтобы отступы (margins) не схлопывались:

```js
let humbs = document.querySelectorAll('.humb');

[...humbs].map(el => el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  this.classList.toggle('active');
}));
```

```css
.humb {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #7a52b3;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.bar-wrap {
  transition: 0.2s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bar {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 3px auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.v2 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 8px auto;
}

.active .bar-wrap:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(0, 100%) rotate(45deg);
}

.active .bar-wrap:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(0, -100%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.active .bar-wrap:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="humb">
  <div class="bar-wrap"><span class="bar"></span></div>
  <div class="bar-wrap"><span class="bar"></span></div>
  <div class="bar-wrap"><span class="bar"></span></div>
</div>
<div class="humb">
  <div class="bar-wrap"><span class="bar v2"></span></div>
  <div class="bar-wrap"><span class="bar v2"></span></div>
  <div class="bar-wrap"><span class="bar v2"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, круто, попробую разобрать решение

Comment: @Алина Обратите внимание, что `overflow: hidden` также обязателен для `.humb` (не знаю почему так назвал)

Answer (score 5):

В процентах на все случаи жизни не подскажу, но подскажу как сделать в вашем случае.

И так у нас есть 3 полоски, при нажатии мы скрываем тот что по середине и поворачиваем 1-ый и 3-ий на 45 и -45 градусов соответственно. Теперь всё что нам надо это совместить центры полосок, после поворота, но это тоже самое что совместить центры и без поворота, т.е. наложить их друг на друга, потому что поворот происходит относительно центра полосок. А чтобы их совместить нам нужно знать расстояние между полосками (`margin`) и высоту полосок (`height`). Обе переменные нам известны - это `6px` и `4px` соответственно. значит нам надо первую сместить на сумму `height + margin`, а вторую на `-(height + margin)`. Ниже пример как я это релизовал:

```js
const hamb = document.querySelector("#hamb");
const popup = document.querySelector("#popup");
const menu = document.querySelector("#menu").cloneNode(1);
const body = document.body;

hamb.addEventListener("click", hambHandler);

function hambHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  popup.classList.toggle("open");
  hamb.classList.toggle("active");
  body.classList.toggle("noscroll");
  renderPopup();
}

function renderPopup() {
  popup.appendChild(menu);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --menu-line-vertical-margin: 6px;
  --menu-line-height: 4px;
  --offsetY: calc(var(--menu-line-vertical-margin) + var(--menu-line-height));
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background: #7a52b3;
}


/* меню бургер */

.hamb {
  display: none;
}


/* расположение обьектов в меню бургер */

.popup {
  display: none;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar__wrap .menu>li>a {
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar__wrap .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .hamb {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .hamb__field {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .bar {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: var(--menu-line-height);
    margin: var(--menu-line-vertical-margin) auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: 0.2s;
  }
  .popup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 75px;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  .popup.open {
    left: 0;
  }
  /* контент в меню бургере */
  .popup .menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: start;
    padding: 50px 0;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  /* контент в меню бургере */
  .popup .menu>li>a {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #3f3f3f;
  }
  .hamb__field.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .hamb__field.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translate(0, var(--offsetY)) rotate(45deg);
  }
  .hamb__field.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translate(0, calc(-1 * var(--offsetY))) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  body.noscroll {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Adaptive header for site</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar__wrap">
        <div class="hamb">
          <div class="hamb__field" id="hamb">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <ul class="menu" id="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Benefits</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="popup" id="popup"></div>



  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```